# functional equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I have the following question:
Let $f$ be an analytic function satisfying the functional equation: $f(z)=u(z)f(a-z)$ where $a$ is a real constant. Let $g$ be another function satisfying the same functional equation. In this case I asking if $f=g$. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: NO, a=0, u(z)=1.

Comment: A more profound example is $u(z)=1,$ but $a=2\pi.$ In that case, both $\sin$ and $\cos$ satisfy the equation.

Comment: You must say, WHERE is your function analytic,
to obtain a non-trivial answer.

Comment: The function is analytic in the whole complex plane.

Comment: Note that your equation is linear in $f$, so if there is one nonzero solution there is at least a one-parameter family of them. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution by Robert Israel, the uniqueness question (which was asked) is not addressed.

Of course one cannot conclude that $f=g$, because if $f$ satisfies the equation,
and $p$ is any function such that $p(z)=p(a-z)$ then $fp$ satisfies the equation.
And this is the general description of all solutions because if $f$ and $g$ satisfy the
equation, then their ratio has the property that $p(z)=p(a-z)$.

Comment: See my comment to the question.  $0$ is always a solution. As soon as you have a nonzero solution, you have nonuniqueness.  If there are no nonzero solutions, the solution $0$ is unique.

Answer (score 2):

A necessary condition for a nonzero solution is  $u(z) u(a-z) = 1$.  If that is true and $u$ is entire, it has an entire square root.  Now $\sqrt{u(z)} \sqrt{u(a-z)} = u(a/2) = \pm 1$: if it is $1$, then $f(z) = \sqrt{u(z)}$ is a solution.  If it is $-1$, then $f(z) = (z - a/2) \sqrt{u(z)}$ is a solution.